# kubectl status.phase=Running return wrong results

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When I run:

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Running
```

I see:

```
NAME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
k8s-fbd7b     2/2     Running   0          5m5s
testm-45gfg   1/2     Error     0          22h
```

I don't understand why this command gives me pod that are in Error status?
According to [K8S api](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase), there is no such thing `STATUS=Error`.

How can I get only the pods that are in this Error status?

When I run:

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Failed
```

It tells me that there are no pods in that status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply grep the Error pods using the

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespces | grep Error
```

Remove all error pods from the cluster

```
kubectl delete pod `kubectl get pods --namespace <yournamespace> | awk '$3 == "Error" {print $1}'` --namespace <yournamespace>
```

Mostly Pod failures return explicit error states that can be observed in the status field

Error :

Your pod is crashed, it was able to schedule on node successfully but crashed after that. To debug it more you can use different methods or commands

```
kubectl describe pod <Pod name > -n <Namespace>
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-pod-replication-controller/#my-pod-is-crashing-or-otherwise-unhealthy

Answer (score 6):

Using the `kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Failed` command you can display all Pods in the `Failed` phase.

`Failed` means that all containers in the Pod have terminated, and at least one container has terminated in failure (see: [Pod phase](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase)):

> Failed - All containers in the Pod have terminated, and at least one container has terminated in failure. That is, the container either exited with non-zero status or was terminated by the system.

In your example, both Pods are in the `Running` phase because at least one container is still running in each of these Pods.:

> Running - The Pod has been bound to a node, and all of the containers have been created. At least one container is still running, or is in the process of starting or restarting.

You can check the current phase of Pods using the following command:

```
$ kubectl get pod -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.status.phase}{"\n"}{end}'
```

Let's check how this command works:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME    READY   STATUS   
app-1   1/2     Error   
app-2   0/1     Error   

$ kubectl get pod -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.status.phase}{"\n"}{end}'
app-1   Running
app-2   Failed
```

As you can see, only the `app-2` Pod is in the `Failed` phase. There is still one container running in the `app-1` Pod, so this Pod is in the `Running` phase.

To list all pods with the `Error` status, you can simply use:

```
$ kubectl get pods -A | grep Error
default       app-1   1/2     Error     
default       app-2   0/1     Error
```

Additionally, it's worth mentioning that you can check the state of all containers in Pods:

```
$ kubectl get pod -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.status.containerStatuses[*].state}{"\n"}{end}'
app-1   {"terminated":{"containerID":"containerd://f208e2a1ff08c5ce2acf3a33da05603c1947107e398d2f5fbf6f35d8b273ac71","exitCode":2,"finishedAt":"2021-08-11T14:07:21Z","reason":"Error","startedAt":"2021-08-11T14:07:21Z"}} {"running":{"startedAt":"2021-08-11T14:07:21Z"}}
app-2   {"terminated":{"containerID":"containerd://7a66cbbf73985efaaf348ec2f7a14d8e5bf22f891bd655c4b64692005eb0439b","exitCode":2,"finishedAt":"2021-08-11T14:08:50Z","reason":"Error","startedAt":"2021-08-11T14:08:50Z"}}
```

Comment: Thank you that is very informative but it didn't answer yet on the question. "How can I get only the pods that are in this Error status?" In my example I want to get only `testm-45gfg`

Comment: I have already answered that question. Take a look at the sentence: `To list all pods with the Error status, you can simply use:`

Comment: This status column is totally confusing.Basically pod status has nothing to do with the pod. it just reports some of container's ....state or reason or.. who knows.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an overkill `go-template` based attempt:

```
kubectl  get pods -o go-template='{{range $index, $element := .items}}{{range .status.containerStatuses}}{{range .state }}{{if .reason }}{{if (eq  .reason "Error") }}{{$element.metadata.name}} {{$element.metadata.namespace}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'
job1-stn45 default
```

My pod status:

```
k get pod
NAME                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
foo                          1/1     Running            1          2d11h
nginx-0                      1/1     Running            3          5d10h
nginx-2                      1/1     Running            3          5d10h
nginx-1                      1/1     Running            3          5d10h
job1-stn45                   0/1     Error              0          113m
update-test-27145740-82z7s   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          96m
update-test-27145500-7f2l9   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          5h36m
```